# Unable to get this popup to go above the cursor

Tags: jquery, popup, cursor-position

Ok, so I have this jsfiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/9RxLM/1751/

I am using it exactly like that in my page, because I have no access to the head tag, only the body for now.

I don't understand how I can give it a `.css({marginTop: '-1em'}).` in the actual jQuery, and than even in the `.popup` CSS give it another negative margin top (`margin: -1.5em 10% 0;`), but yet it still doesn't obey and wants to display whereever it wants to display.

How can I get this to popup so that the cursor is underneath of the popup when the cursor is over the question mark?

Comment: Just a thought: why not use jQuery UI's [`tooltip`](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position something above the cursor, you first need the coordinates of the cursor. What you need is `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`, then set the CSS top and left properites relative to the mouse coordinates.

I changed this line in your fiddle:

```
jQuery(this).prevAll("span.popup:first").stop(true, true).css({top: event.pageY-20}).fadeIn('slow', function() {
     jQuery(this).nextAll("span.parent:first").stop(true, true).addClass("backdrop");
```

Here it is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/9RxLM/1754/

Comment: Ok, so this works good in your test, but for some reason it is not working in the live environment...  In the live environment it is too far down the page.  If I give it a top value of `0` it doesn't even go to the very top of the page, so there is something else influencing this here.  But you definitely got me started and helped a bit here.  Thanks +1

Comment: Ah...  try setting the `position` to `fixed` instead of `absolute`.  If that doesn't work, use the `offset().top` property instead of the CSS `top` property.

Comment: OMG, so I just did `var oTop = (jQuery(this).parent().offset().top - jQuery(this).prevAll("span.popup:first").offset().top) - 60;` and than used `.css({top: oTop})` on the element and that did EXACTLY what I wanted.  Thanks for your help!  YOU ROCK!